# bash regex command equivalent in windows cmd script

Tags: windows, command

What would be the equivalent of this bash command:

```
[[ $(uname) =~ NT-6.3 ]] && set_win81
```

In windows cmd script?

I was hopping to use something like:

```
if (ver | findstr /C:"Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3") ( goto :set_win81 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would suffice.

```
ver | findstr /i /c:"Version 6.3" >nul && goto :set_win81
```

Here is some code I had squirreled away for this task:

```
@echo off
set "windows="
VER | find  " 4.1." > nul && set windows=W98
VER | find  " 4.0." > nul && set windows=NT
VER | find  " 5.0." > nul && set windows=W2K
VER | find  " 5.1." > nul && set windows=XP
VER | find  " 5.2." > nul && set windows=XP 64-Bit or Server 2003 or Server 2003 R2 
VER | find  " 6.0." > nul && set windows=Vista or server 2008
VER | find  " 6.1." > nul && set windows=Win7 or server 2008 R2
VER | find  " 6.2." > nul && set windows=Windows 8
VER | find  " 6.3." > nul && set windows=Server 2012 R2 or Windows 8.1
if defined windows (
echo %windows%
) else (
echo unknown operating system
)
pause
```

Comment: The Windows version values are: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Your first code sample is an error, too. Should look like the lines in your second sample.

Comment: @Tomalak  Thanks for catching that.  :thumbsup:

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to parsing the output of `ver`, you could use the registry:

```
setlocal 

set reg_info=reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v CurrentVersion
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %%l in ('%reg_info%') do set win_ver=%%l

if "%win_ver%" equ "6.2" goto :set_win80
if "%win_ver%" equ "6.3" goto :set_win81

REM etc etc
```

The key point is that you can use a `for /f` loop with a few settings to parse multi-line, multi-column data like the output of `reg query`.

Comment: Your for loop variable needs an extra percent on both `%l` for a batch file.

Comment: Absolutely. Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: Get windows Version numbers
set ver=""
set con="Microsoft Windows Version 6.3"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%G in ('ver') do set ver=%%G
echo found version %ver%
if %%ver EQU %%con (
goto set_win81)

echo NO win81
exit/B

:set_win81 
echo win81
exit/B
```